# Eclipse can't see Java

Tags: java, eclipse

So I'm throughly confused. Eclipse both does and doesn't see Java. I'm running Eclipse Photon (4.8.0), Java 10.0.2, and macOS High Sierra 10.13.6. In the Eclipse preferences, under the Oomph menu, it does show the accurate location of the JDK, but there is no Java menu in the preferences, and it does not recognize any of my project files and does not compile.

Edit: Screenshots showing a project properties pane and the settings panel when searching for Java and a link to the Eclipse About config:

[Eclipse About Config](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ftJMlkATcxedeDSg_kFz3jJI7urudYKcNAijHlkCHuc/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: Project Properties pane]

[image: Search result in Preferences]

Comment: Did you actually choose to install the Java Developer Tools? It sounds like you did not.

Comment: @AlexShesterov I did not use brew. I downloaded Eclipse directly from their site.

Comment: @nitind I downloaded the JDKSE from oracles site.

Comment: The *Eclipse* Java Developer Tools. What did you download from eclipse.org?

Comment: Sometimes you need to set a Project Facet (Right-click the project -> Properties -> Project Facets).

Comment: @nitind It was earlier this summer, so I don't remember specifically, but I'm pretty sure it was the download labeled "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers"

Comment: @Pranav That's irrelevant since Eclipse doesn't utilize java _at all_ (even though it knows where the JDK is). It's not a per-project issue. This is across the whole program. Plus, Project Facets doesn't even show up at all under the project properties.

Comment: Eclipse is written in Java. I would right click the project, go to the build path menu, and then check whether the path to the Java system library is set correctly.

Comment: @ifly6 The build path menu does not appear

Comment: Sure the option shows up there! Could be a cross platform issue? I can see Project Facets in project properties on Windows. Plus you can't see the Build Path option either? It too should be there in Project Properties

Comment: @Pranav `Sure the options show up there!` Um, no, they don't. I just said that. That's why I asked this question here in the first place, because things aren't working like they're supposed to.

Comment: Give us some screenshots or something, like the About dialog's Configuration details, because this isn't making any sense.

Comment: The post has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, with the config information, it looks like you downloaded Eclipse IDE for Testers (note the `eclipse.product` property). I don't know the exact purpose of that package but though it does have at least parts of the JDT features, it is clearly missing a lot of stuff for Java development.

The Java VM seen by Oomph is simply what it's been able to discern is available on your system and highlights which is being used to run eclipse (it isn't showing eclipse defined JREs).

So, you'll need to download Eclipse IDE for Java Developers or one of several other packages that include Java development tools (like Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, among others). https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/

Comment: Thank you sir, this was indeed the problem. I don't know how I ended with the wrong type of Eclipse, but I did somehow. As a side question, do you have a quick explanation for what Oomph is? I read Eclipse's site on it, but it didn't make sense.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Oomph, except as an eclipse installer, though it seems it can provision workspaces, too, and do a bunch of other things for development shops to ensure they have installed everything they need. I stick with the packages downloads myself, since I'm clearer where I am with that (eclipse installed with Oomph) have components in different places compared a package extract. Oomph still seems to be there under the covers for package installs but that's all I know.

Answer (score 0):

Without a screenshot, I can't be sure but it looks like your project is just a plain project. Right click on it then go to Configure>Convert to Faceted Form at which point the project facets page will show up and you can click the Java facet, then click "Apply and Close".

The project should now be a Java project and you can set build path and so on. If not, then more info about the project would help, perhaps a screenshot of Project Properties page (right click on the project and select Properties).

Comment: Updated the post with some screenshots and a config link. "Convert to Faceted Form" does not appear under the projects Configure menu. The only thing that appears is "Configure and Detect Nested Projects".